How to move an azure app service to a new shared app service plan
I have been banging my head against a wall for this one. I originally would deploy every app service (wordpress, database) etc under their own app service plan for organization. It has been costing me a fortune since I do not take advantage of the resources and should be hosting multiple sites per app service plan. Live and learn!
So I recently created a new app service plan with plenty of vcpus and ram to host about 10 sites. I have put this app service plan under the same region as most of my apps. When I go to my app services and select change app service and select the drop down , the new app service plan I created for sharing is not in the list. So is it not possible to move an app service to a new app service plan in a different resource group or does this have to be done on creation of the app service?
If its not possible what is my best route for cloning my app service and then redeploying it with the shared app service plan?

Are both the App Service Plan and the target App Service Plan in the same resource group?

They are not in the same resource group.

That might be the issue, since the app service plans are not in the same resource group, that's why you're unable to see the target plan in the dropdown.
please try creating app service plan in same resource group.

I tried moving an App Service to a new app service plan and faced a similar issue.
I've referred this doc to know how to manage the app service plans.

As you mentioned in your comment, I tried to move my app to a new app service plan in a different resource group, but I couldn't find the service plan in the dropdown.

Below, you can see that I've created app service plans with a different resource group, a different region, and a different operating system.




But I can only see the app service plans that are in the same resource group, within the same region, and with the same OS type in the dropdown box.



The app service plan was changed successfully.


So, we need to ensure that the target app service plan has the same resource group, region, and OS type as the source app service plan


The new app service plan is NOT listed in dropdown is due to that it's in the different resource group. As mentioned in doc:

To move the app to another app service plan, you can check the official doc:

You can move an app to another App Service plan, as long as the source plan and the target plan are in the same resource group and geographical region and of the same OS type.

Also mentioned:

Azure deploys each new App Service plan into a deployment unit, internally called a webspace. Each region can have many webspaces, but your app can only move between plans that are created in the same webspace.

You can find the webspace in overview -> JSON view.
For your scenario, you can consider below options:

Create the app service plan in same resource group and same geographical region as the current App Service plan. Then you can move the app.

or you can try the clone option within azure portal, you can do it too using AZ cli, It can be found under web app -> Development Tools -> Clone App '(Unfortunately the clone option is available only in windows web apps, and not available for Function Apps)':


You can also refer to the link here and here for the details.
